# mySQL multiple Joins for 5 tables with timeout errors

Tags: mysql, sql, join, timeout

I have 5 tables:

Categories_groups_cat1

```
id|order|title(text)
```

Categories_vs_groups

```
id|categories_groups_cat1_id|categories_id
```

Categories

```
id|title(text)
```

Offers

```
id|category (text)
```

Coupons

```
id|category (text)
```

I want to display titles from Categories_groups_cat1 only if:

Exists at least one row in Categories_vs_groups via categories_groups_cat1_id column (Categories_vs_groups.categories_groups_cat1_id==Categories_groups_cat1.id)
**AND** categories_id from Categories_vs_groups exists as at least one row to table Categories (Categories.id==Categories_vs_groups.categories_id) **AND** where have at least one row in table Offers or Coupons via category column (offers.category==categories.title)!!

I do the following but I have timeout because the tables offers or coupons is more tha 500000.

```
SELECT 
            offers.category_gr, 
            categories.id, categories.title_gr,
            categories_vs_groups.categories_id,
            categories_vs_groups.categories_groups_cat1_id AS cat1,
            categories_vs_groups.categories_groups_cat2_id AS cat2

        FROM offers
        LEFT JOIN categories
        ON categories.title_gr=offers.category_gr
        LEFT JOIN categories_vs_groups
        ON categories_vs_groups.categories_id=categories.id

        WHERE categories.title_gr='$row_best_offer[category_gr]'

        GROUP BY categories.id
        order by categories.id
```

Comment: hosted environment that times out after 60 secs? `show variables where variable_name in ('wait_timeout','interactive_timeout')`

Comment: No! But even that it is for a website. I need to load in 2-3 sec!

Comment: `show create table offers`, etc for all 3 tables ... we can then ponder your index strategy

Comment: Your  `where` clause is undoing your first `left join`.  And you might as well use `categories.title_gr` in the `select` rather than `offers.category_gr`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the right set-up, your query should not take more than 60 seconds.

Your `where` clause is undoing the first `LEFT JOIN` (and you probably don't need the second either.  Because you are aggregating by categories, I would suggest starting with that.  Then, the `offers` table is only needed for filtering, so you should consider whether it is really necessary.

So, consider this query:

```
SELECT c.category_gr, c.id, c.title_gr,
       cvg.categories_id, cvg.categories_groups_cat1_id AS cat1,
       cvg.categories_groups_cat2_id AS cat2
FROM categories c JOIN
     offers o 
     ON c.title_gr = o.category_gr LEFT JOIN
     categories_vs_groups cvg
     ON cvg.categories_id = c.id
WHERE c.title_gr = '$row_best_offer[category_gr]'
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.id;
```

For best results, you want indexes on `categories(title_gr, category_gr, id)`, `offers(category_gr)`, and `categories_vs_groups(categories_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

1. instead of using condtion `WHERE categories.title_gr='$row_best_offer[category_gr]'` in where clause, put it in On clause
2. First left join is unnecessary.

   SELECT 
   offers.category_gr, 
               categories.id, categories.title_gr,
               categories_vs_groups.categories_id,
               categories_vs_groups.categories_groups_cat1_id AS cat1,
               categories_vs_groups.categories_groups_cat2_id AS cat2

   FROM offers
   JOIN categories
    ON 
    (categories.title_gr=offers.category_gr 
    and categories.title_gr='$row_best_offer[category_gr]' )

   LEFT JOIN categories_vs_groups
    ON categories_vs_groups.categories_id=categories.id

   GROUP BY categories.id
    order by categories.id